# How can convert formatting text by flutter to formatting as html

Tags: flutter, web, formatting, text-editor, quill

I develop app to create notes
and i can formatting the note by text editor but how can translate this format to web because my app is linking with website
how can convert formatting from flutter mobile to web and reverse

I think i will using flutter_quil to format text but how convert the formatting to web and reverse

hint: the website is developed by another language but linking with same API that mobile app uses it

Answer (score 0):

Either you create your own domain specific language and translate it in your web frontend. (for example a bold text you could check in the web for [b]my text[/b] and mark the text between bold). I'm not sure if your flutter_quill can already export it like this, if not you have to do it on your own ... or you can maybe use element embedding.

At the Flutter Forward event element embedding was presented, you could theoretically insert your editor as a Flutter widget into your current frontend. Here is a demo:

https://flutter-forward-demos.web.app/#/